# Alguien seria tan amable de decirme como logro una salida de estas cuentas pero en horizontal, una al lado de la otra?. Gracias

Tags: python-3.x

#la salida que me brinda este codigo es solo de forma vertical

```
  aa=["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]#lista
    l=[]
    for i in aa:
       b=i.split()
       l.append(b)
    for i in l:
       print('  {}\n'
          '{} {}\n'
          ' -----'.format(i[0],i[1],i[2]))
```

Comment: Elimina los `\n` que hay en los strings.

Answer (score 0):

Cada `\n` que pones dentro del string a imprimir se convierte en un salto de línea.

La solución es eliminar los `\n` de sobra:

```
aa=["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]#lista
l=[]
for i in aa:
   b=i.split()
   l.append(b)
for i in l:
   print('  {} {} {} -----'.format(i[0],i[1],i[2]))
```

produce:

```
  32 + 698 -----
  3801 - 2 -----
  45 + 43 -----
  123 + 49 -----

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Ahora si quieres eliminar **todos** los salto de linea, debes indicar explicitamente a `print()` que no agregue un `\n` al final. Para eso, agrega el parámetro `end=''` en la llamada, indicando el caracter a usar al final de la línea:

```
print('  {} {} {} -----'.format(i[0],i[1],i[2]), end='')
```

lo que produce:

```
  32 + 698 -----  3801 - 2 -----  45 + 43 -----  123 + 49 -----
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Esa fue mi primer solución. El tema es que necesito que cada operación quede formateada: numero(i[o]) y debajo operando ((- o +)i[1]) y el otro numero(i[2]). Por eso el \n.  Ese es el formato que necesito.